# merge multiple csv file using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python , i am looking to merge multiple csv files .I have two files as follows

```
CSV1:
startp endp slack
S1 E1 -0.15
S4 E2 -10
S3 E3 -3.2

CSV2:
startp endp slack
S1 E1 -0.12
S2 E2 -4
S3 E3 -1.2

Merged csv : i want like this
startp endp slack_csv1 slack_csv2
S1 E1 -0.15 -0.12
S4 E2 -10 
S2 E2        -4
S3 E3 -3.2 -1.2

I wrote code like this 
    for file_name in all_csv"
        df=pd.read_csv(file_name)
        if i==0"
      df_t = df
      i=1
df_t=pd.merge(df_t,df)
print("after merge", df_t,df)
```

output for df_t is empty after second merge. If i try to merge on=endp , i get an error. Please help to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm assuming your CSVs have commas where you put spaces.

I'm not sure what the `"` was for after the `for` statement, but I formatted it to what I think you meant to write.

You were close to having it. You just have to specify some more parameters for the [pd.merge() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html).

You may want to change the suffixes parameter to accept variables that indicate which file they are from (see below for an extended answer that addresses this).

```py
all_csv = ["csv1.csv", "csv2.csv"]
i = 0
for file_name in all_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    if i == 0:
        df_t = df
        i = 1

df_t = pd.merge(df_t, df, on=['startp', 'endp'], how='outer', suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
print("after merge", df_t)
```

outputs:

```
  startp endp  slack_1  slack_2
0     S1   E1       -0.15       -0.12
1     S4   E2      -10.00         NaN
2     S3   E3       -3.20       -1.20
3     S2   E2         NaN       -4.00
```

### Alternate solution but handles more than 2 files

Here I use `pd.DataFrame.merge()` instead of `pd.merge()`, but they accomplish the same task. I'm renaming the column before combining it, which means more than 2 files can be combined. This is just one way. You can reformat your prior code to handle more than 2 files as well.

```
df_combined = None
for csv_file in all_csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    df = df.rename(columns={'slack': 'slack_' + csv_file})
    if df_combined is None:
        df_combined = df.copy()
    else:
        df_combined = df_combined.merge(df, how='outer', on=['startp', 'endp'])

print(df_combined)
```